# Is there a more elegant way to handling contribution pages that have ended?

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page

When a contribution page passes its end date, you get the following error:
[image]

Is there a way to let the contribution page load, but display something like what is displayed on events?

[image]

Ideally it would say something like.

- This page is no longer accepting contributions.
- This contribution page has ended.
- Contributions are no longer being accepted on this page.

In the meantime, we are simply redirecting the pages.

Answer (score 2):

This [module](https://civicrm.org/extensions/disabled-page-redirect) might be what you need

> The extension allows a default contribution page to be configured (by domain), and blocks disabling or deleting of this page. Browsers accessing a disabled contribution page are redirected to the default page.

or, now i reread your post :-), could be a good place to add a new feature since i think you are saying 'my pages are not disabled, they are just past their use-by-date'